# Tab through disabled="disabled" button in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-9, accessibility

This is an issues for accessibility - In chrome, these buttons can be tabbed through, but Internet explorer does not allow tabbing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems that it's a Chrome issue, not IE. Actually if a button is disabled it's not meant to be focused. Again, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Why is it an accessibility issue - if the button is disabled, it's not meant to be accessible; that's kinda the whole point of disabling it, isn't it?

Comment: Just because you can't press a button doesn't mean you shouldn't inform the user that there is a disabled button on the page. Think about login forms where they disable the button until you fill it out correctly, and the validation happens after the user leaves the input.

Answer (score 0):

For w3c accessibility purpose, you can use **readonly** instead of **disabled**
and remove the **onfocus** functionality when it is readonly.

Example below:

```
 ng-readonly="isReadOnly"  ng-focus="(isReadOnly) ? '' : onFocus($event)"
```